# Database design for an inverse to-many relationship in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, database-design, relationships

I am working on a personal app that uses core data. I am trying to design a database that can help me obtain certain food items based on a specific set of nutrients that I provide. meaning that, if a food item contains any of these nutrients, it must be returned. So the relationship between the nutrients and foods is many-to-many.

following the relational database approach, I can do this using 3 tables; 1 for the nutrients, 1 for the food items, and a mapping table containing nutrientIDs and foodItemID. this approach is good and can work easily. But since core data is not a relational database, I cannot apply this approach here.

I had the idea of not using the mapping table and include nutrients directly in the foods table as a string where each nutrient is separated by "-", then fetch the results using NSPredicate. I am not very sure about this approach, and I would greatly appreciate any ideas on how to go around this problem using core data techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a mapping table.  Just assign a to-Many relationship with an inverse to-Many relationship and Core Data will create the mapping table.

If you decide, later that you need something like a quantity for the relationship **then** you want a third entity for the join.  That entity would then have a to-Many relationship to Food, a to-Many relationship to Nutrient and each of those would have a to-One inverse.  That middle entity would then contain the meta information about the relationship (quantity, unit of measure, etc.).